# DVD -playback function

Tags: dvd

Can I put a DVD in my DVD-drive and check it or should I download some other programme together with Ubuntu? Example: Windows has mediaplayer. What does Ubuntu have?

Answer (score 0):

Rhythmbox is the default media player in Ubuntu. But just like windows media player can't play DVD natively, you have to add some extra software.  In Ubuntu make sure that you have Ubuntu Restricted Extras installed.  If not you can install by just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Or you can use VLC.  To download, and more info visit the [Website](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html)

Comment: To install VLC just run `sudo apt-get install vlc` or use the software center. (It's a very would media player and comes with the "right" codecs.)